# How do I set initial values on a Django form using CreateView

Tags: python, django-views, django-forms

I have a form and wish to set some default values in the fields. My original solution using the *View* class works

```
# forms.py
ResultForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Result
        fields = ("date", "club", "goals_for", "goals_against")
    ...
    @staticmethod
    def get_initial():
        initial = {
            'date': datetime.today().date(),
            'goals_for': 0,
            'goals_against': 0,
        }
        return initial
```

and

```
# views.py
class EnterResultView(View):
    template = 'results/enter_result.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form_class = ResultForm()
        form_class.initial = form_class.get_initial()
        context = {
            'form_class': form_class
        }
        return render(request, self.template, context)
```

But if I convert to a *CreateView* I cannot get the fields to initialise

```
# views.py
class EnterResultView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'results/enter_result.html'
    form_class = ResultForm
    form_class.initial = form_class.get_initial()
```

What must I do?

[EDIT added template]

```
<!--  results/enter_result.html -->
...
        {% for field in view.form_class %}
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right">{{ field.label_tag }}</td>
                <td>{{ field }}</td>
                {% if field.errors %}
                    {% for error in field.errors %}
                        <td class="form-error">{{ error }}</td>
                    {% endfor %}
                {% endif %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views with a [**`FormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin) have a [**`.get_initial()`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_initial), you thus can override this:

```
class EnterResultView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'results/enter_result.html'
    form_class = ResultForm

    def get_initial(self):
        return self.form_class.get_initial()
```

A `CreateView` constructs a form and passes this to the view as `form`, you should *not* use `view.form_class`, since that will construct *another* (new) form, *without* any parameters:

```
{% for field in form %}
    …
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to work even though the *get_initial* method is called every time the form is loaded. I've added my template to the question

Comment: @Psionman: `get_initial` will only set the *initial* data by using the `initial=...` parameter when constructing the form. If you post a form, then the posted data will override the initial data.

Comment: @Psionman: in other words, it will create the `ResultForm` with `ResultForm(initial={'date': ..., 'goals': ..., ...})` like the ones you provided, but how the form will handle that later, of course depends on how you implemented your `ModelForm` and how you are *rendering* the form.

Comment: @Psionman: based however on your generic `EnterResultView(View)`, you did use a `.initial` attribute.

Comment: I am loading the form from the menu each time. If I change the code to that that you suggested the fields do not initialise

Comment: @Psionman: what do you mean with *from the menu*. It looks very "strange" to set `.initial` on a form *after* the form has been constructed. Do you by any chance override the constructor (the `...` in the `ModelForm`).

Comment: I understand that post would not initialise the form. If I call it from the menu I expect it to set the defaults. When I do, the get_initial method is called, but the data does not appear in the fields. The only other code in the form class is related to validation

Comment: @Psionman: hold on, you use `form_class`, but in a `CreateView`, the form is passed as `form` to the template. By using `view.form_class`, you are constructing a *new* form in the *tempate*.

Comment: it's (note colon)
    def get_initial(self):